Drupal Entity Registration module : account for anonymous users
My goal :
When an anonymous user register to an event (bound to registration entity), I would like to provide additional fields to let him also create his account, instead having just an "email to associate with this registration" in DB. So in one form, the newcomer would register to the event and the website.
My question :
What is the cleaner way to do that with Registration module ? Just some hooks on the registration form ?
thanks
